# Which weapon should I use for the "12 Days of Winterval" achievement?

Tags: achievements, worms-reloaded

The **12 Days of Winterval** achievement for *Worms: Reloaded* reads `deal exactly 12 damage to a worm with 100 health`. What weapon can I use in order to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the Uzi. It does 1 damage per hit, so if you control where you aim, you can do just 12 damage to the enemy worm.

Alternatively, you can use Teleport/Jetpack to get 12 fall damage.

Just set up a custom game with 4 human teams. You should get it in a few minutes.

Comment: I found using the Teleport and dropping worms in the same place by trial and error to be the handiest way, as the Uzi shoots a little too fast for me to measure its DPS properly.

Comment: I used splash damage from the bazooka. You can keep re-starting the level and firing the bazooka near the enemy until one hits for exactly twelve damage.

Answer (score 3):

I used a [custom map](http://www.jamespoel.co.uk/filestore/12%20Days%20of%20Winterval.lds) I found. It worked very well.

How-to video:

Just walk off the high ledge to do exactly 12 fall damage to your worm.

No credit to me, I just found this solution elsewhere and reposted!